# How to display the laravel 404 page?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I am still new in using laravel. For the first project that I tried, the 404 page error that shows up is the 404 page provided in laravel. [Laravel's 404 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPfvA.png)

But for my second project, the 404 page is showing up the old 404 page. [Old 404 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiHAr.png)

I'm not sure what changes I did that led to it. Is there a way to know? How do I change it so that it will show the 404 page made by laravel?

Comment: Different Laravel versions? (Btw, your "_old_" 404 page is actually the _new_ 404 page)

Comment: That's weird. I did both projects using Laravel 5.7. Does that mean the "old" 404 page is the 404 page used by Laravel 5.8 and above?

Comment: Yes, that "old" page is used by Laravel >=5.8. Check `composer.json` or run `php artisan` to get your Laravel version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default 404 error page moved to minimal design in Laravel 5.8

So you can grab the 5.7 one from [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/views/404.blade.php)

And override it by placing a `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` file containing

```html
@extends('errors::illustrated-layout')

@section('code', '404')
@section('title', __('Page Not Found'))

@section('image')
    <div style="background-image: url({{ asset('/svg/404.svg') }});" class="absolute pin bg-cover bg-no-repeat md:bg-left lg:bg-center">
    </div>
@endsection

@section('message', __('Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.'))
```

And get the `public/svg/404.svg` file from [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.7/public/svg/404.svg) if you don't have it already and place it in `public/svg` folder